# PhpStorm: "Executing 'Less' task" keeps flashing

Tags: less, phpstorm, webstorm

I am using PhpStorm 2020.2.4 and am experiencing a strange behaviour:
there's a message popping up every second in the PhpStorm taskbar: "Executing 'less' task" .. even when doing nothing. Any ideas what could be causing this?
I configured a File watcher for .less but this shouldn't happen in idle mode.

[image]

Comment: 1) Check `idea.log` for possible hints 2) Enable "Show console" (or whatever that option name is) in that File Watcher settings -- it may also give some hints. Right now: maybe for some unknown yet reason your file watcher gets executed over and over again?..

Comment: please also attach a screenshot of how did you configure your file watcher.